# How to get my random number generator to not give the same result every time? (So I dont have to restart the program)

Tags: java, random

How to get my random number generator (Java) to not give the same result every time? (So I dont have to restart the program)
I have even tried to add in 2 different generators to see if that would change the outcome, but it dousnt. If anyone knows a meathod please let me know.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;


public class RNG {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //The frame
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setSize(500, 300);
        frm.setResizable(true);
        frm.setTitle("Random Number Generator");
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setLayout(null);

        //The button
        JButton btn = new JButton("Refresh Number!");
        btn.setBounds(120, 100, 200, 50);
        frm.add(btn);

        //The generator
        int rand3;
        int min = 1;
        int max = 100;
        int rand2 = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);

        Random rand1 = new Random();
        rand3 = rand1.nextInt(1,100);


        //The actionlistener
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(rand3*rand2/100);

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: The random number is generated with the `rand1.nextInt(1,100);` method call. Simply call that method again to get another random number instead of just saving the result of that call in a variable and always using that variable.

Comment: If you assign the result of a method call to a variable, the using that variable will not automatically call the method again. It will only get called one time for the initial assignment to the variable.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but if I understand right, you want to print random number from 1 to 100, just modify ActionPerformed method.

```
//The actionlistener
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(rand1.nextInt(100));

        }
    });
```

You get the same random number because you are calling method nextInt only one time in main method.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your trying to do is print a new random number every time that the button is clicked. If that is the case consider the code below.

```
//The actionlistener
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     System.out.println((int) (Math.random() * 100));

   }
});
```